# List Does Not Reappear on Window Resize

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I have a dropdown manu that I have made responsive using CSS and jQuery. If the window is shrunk the mobile nav appears just fine, but if you expand and close the menu, and then resize your window larger, the desktop nav does not reappear due to the inline display: none added by the slideToggle. I can't figure out, for the life of me, how to get the menu to reappear when the window size is increased again.

HTML

```
<div class="nav">
        <div class="mobile-nav">Navigation</div>
        <ul class="primary">
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a class="has-drop">Link w/ Children <span></span></a>
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a class="has-drop" href="#link">Link w/ Children <span></span></a>
                <ul class="drop">
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="#link">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
.clear{clear:both}
.nav{display:block;width:100%;background:#222}
.mobile-nav{visibility:hidden;padding:0;height:0;background:#222}
ul.primary{background:#222;list-style:none;height:45px;min-width:350px;position:relative;margin:10px 0 0 0;padding:0;float:right;display:block}
ul.primary li{float:left;display:inline;font-weight:bold;font-size:13px;max-width:100%}
ul.primary li a,ul.drop li a{display:block;padding:10px;color:white;text-decoration:none}
ul.drop li a{padding:5px}
ul.primary li a:hover,ul.drop li a:hover{background:#444}
ul.primary li,ul.drop li{font-family:"Helvetica Neue","Helvetica",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif}
ul.primary li.active>a{background:#444}
a.has-drop{cursor:pointer}
a.has-drop span{margin:-8px 0 0 5px;width:10px;height:5px;float:right;background:url("drop-caret.png") no-repeat center right}
li.active>a.has-drop span{margin:-8px 0 0 5px;width:10px;height:5px;float:right;background:url("drop-caret-up.png") no-repeat center right}
ul.drop{display:none;z-index:999;position:relative;margin:0;padding:0;min-width:100%;width:auto;list-style:none;background:#242424;border:0}
ul.drop li{float:none;font-weight:normal}
@media only screen and (max-width:767px){
nav{display:block;width:100%;border:0 solid white;padding:10px 0}
.mobile-nav{visibility:visible;height:auto;margin:0 5px;padding:10px 0;font-weight:bold;color:white;cursor:pointer;background:url("mobile-nav.png") no-repeat center right}
ul.primary{float:none;display:none;height:auto;margin:0;padding:0}
ul.primary li{display:block;float:none;border-bottom:1px solid #444}
ul.primary li:last-child{border-bottom:0}
ul.drop li,ul.primary li.active{border-bottom:0}
ul.drop li a{text-indent:15px;font-size:12px;font-style:italic}
a.has-drop span{margin:5px 0 0 5px;width:10px;height:5px;float:right;background:url("drop-caret.png") no-repeat center right}
li.active>a.has-drop span{margin:5px 0 0 5px;width:10px;height:5px;float:right;background:url("drop-caret-up.png") no-repeat center right}}​
```

jQuery

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(document).ready(function () {
$j('ul.primary li').click(function () {
var a = this;
if ($j('ul', this).is(':visible')) {
    $j('ul', this).slideUp(function () {
        $j(a).removeClass('active')
    })
} else {
    $j('ul.drop').slideUp();
    $j('ul.primary li').removeClass('active');
    $j('ul', this).slideDown();
    $j(a).addClass('active')
}
});
$j('body').click(function (a) {
if (!$j(a.target).is('a')) {
    $j('ul.drop').slideUp();
    $j('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
}
});
$j(function () {
$j('.mobile-nav').click(function (e) {
    $j('.primary').slideToggle(150, "swing");
    e.stopPropagation()
});
$j(window).resize(function() {
    $j('ul.drop').slideUp();
    $j('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
});
})
});
```

Here is the full markup and jQuery: http://jsfiddle.net/mhXkM/

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error your getting in your fiddle.

Comment: If you go to the mobile view, expand the top-level dropdown, then contract, and then resize to desktop view, the list disappears. Here is a link to a video of the error in action: http://screencast.com/t/6f4xHdCoZ

Answer (score 2):

You can use this small snippet to 'un-apply' the `style="display:none;"` that is likely being applied to your list and not removed on resize. This will reset it to `display: (nothing here);` when the windows is resized to more than 768 pixels.

```
$(function(){
     $(window).resize(function(){
         if($(this).width() >= 768){
             $('#your-element-name').css('display', '');
         }
      })
      .resize(); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I have found is to add a removeAttr to the windowResize function like so:

```
$j(window).resize(function() {
$j('ul.drop').slideUp();
$j('ul.primary li').removeClass('active')
});
```

This removes the display: none cause by the mobile view when the window is resized to a desktop size but allows it to be applied again if viewed in a mobile view.